# How can I pass a dictionary name into a function and handle KeyError inside the function?

Tags: python, function, error-handling

I have a function:

```
def print_boardrow(row, content, alt_content):
    for i in row:
        try:
            print(content, end="")
        except KeyError:
            print(alt_content, end="")
```

And I want to call it like this:

```
print_boardrow(row, slot[i[0]][0], "    ")
```

But this wouldnt work as 'i' is defined inside the function and KeyError would be raised before the function is executed. How can I make it work?
(row is a list and slot is a dictionary)

Comment: Can you confirm that *slot* is a dictionary and that *i[0]* is a possible key in that dictionary?

Comment: Slot contains a string and then some numbers like `slot = { "x": ["Sample Content", 0, 1, 5] }`. I should clarify that _row_ is a nested list so when an element in row starts with _["x",_ then Sample Content will be printed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about restructuring the code slightly?

```
def print_boardrow(row, key, alt_content):
  print(row.get(key, alt_content), end='')

print_board_row(row, i[0], '    ')
```

Not sure what the loop inside the original function is achieving so left it out here. The general idea is the use of *get()* which removes the possibility of KeyError because, if the key is not found, the alternative (default) will be returned

Comment: Thanks, so far this works, and I will probably do more restructuring after this. However, _i_ still gives me UnboundLocalError, but I think that doesn't fit in with the question.